# Ffmpeg support rtmp broadcasts from OS X with audio

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, rtmp

I've successfully gotten ffmpeg to stream live video from the built-in webcam on my macbook pro to my rtmp server but I cannot figure out how to get it to also send audio from the built-in microphone.

I've tried both the qtkit device as well as the avfoundation. It appears that neither support an audio stream.

Does ffmpeg support audio capture on a mac?

All of the examples I can find only show audio capture working with the DirectShow device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it isn't supported at this time. With the help of some of the ffmpeg-devel folks I was able to get it working with a patch. I've applied the patch to a fork available here:

https://github.com/realrunner/FFmpeg